# Facebook: Object Invalid Value of type 'product' is invalid because the given value for property 'og:image:url' could not be parsed as type 'url'

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have a two sites with identical contents, but two different domains.
When I try "like" the product on my site, I get the following error:

> Object Invalid Value: Object at URL "http:// bla bla bla " of type 'product' is invalid because the given value '//mylink/content/pro_1228_A.png' for property 'og:image:url' could not be parsed as type 'url'.

But when I reload the page: everything works fine.
Maybe anybody know what is the problem?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are trying to use a relative link.  That won't work.

The value:

```
//mylink/content/pro_1228_A.png
```

Is an incomplete URL.  It needs to be totally complete and able to be resolved:

```
http://[domain]/mylink/content/pro_1228_A.png
```

Comment: yes, but I can not understand why all is works after page reloading and on the another my site :(

Comment: It's likely because whatever was there before got cached on their system.  Use this tool to see what is being scraped, and to force a cache reset, if necessary:  https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=dpoisn.com